# React Router + Webpack 4 + webpack-dev-server - Failed to compile: no such file or directory

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, webpack-dev-server

I am getting a "Failed to compile" error while trying to set up React with Webpack 4 and webpack-dev-server. The exact error showing is:

> Failed to compile
>
> `./node_modules/history/es/index.js`
>
> `Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/vagrant/node_modules/history/es/index.js'`
>
> This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.

In the `node_modules` directory, the file in question indeed exists. However, I checked the files being sent over, and that file (and its siblings) is being sent as `/vagrant/node_modules/history/index.js` with the `es` director missing.

I am not exactly sure what is causing this. Some research suggested things like mismatched casing on imports, but I checked quite a few times and do not see anything like that going on. I am a bit of a noob when it comes to this, though, so I might be missing something obvious.

**EDIT**

Upon further investigation (with the help of Boy With Silver Wings' comment), the error is actually coming from the depths of React Router. [This issue](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5576) demonstrates something close to my issue, but in their version there is duplication of the history modules while mine seems to "move" them.

Comment: Looks related to https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5576

Comment: Ahh, it may be. It looks like their version of this issue duplicates the history modules while mine "moves" them. But it is a step in the right direction, at least.